# Unable to create Contacts Object with salesforce php client, but able to create others

Tags: php, wordpress, api, soap, salesforce

I am trying to create a new Contact object on Salesforce when our customer inputs their info in WordPress form.

What I notice is I am able to create Lead, Account, etc, but not Contact Object in particular.

The AccountId and LastName fields are the only required field in the Organization's Contact. By the fact that I'm able to create Lead and Account, I'm assuming connection parts are working fine.

```
$contact = new stdClass();
$contact->type = "Contact";
$contact->fields = array(  
    "AccountId" => '0016F00002OcBIMQA3', 
    "RecordTypeId" => '0126F000001hG2WQAU',
    "LastName" => "test",

);

try {  
    $result = $sforce_connection->create(array($contact));  
    var_dump($result);  

} catch (Exception $e) {  
    var_dump($e);  
}
```

There are no error messages coming up. There's no error, except, new contact is not created.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I have not tried to use php for this.  However, in a SOQL query the AccountId is rejected and you instead simply type contact.Account not contact.AccountId.  Is it possible that the same problem exists here?  Have you tried

```
$contact->fields = array(  
    "Account" => '0016F00002OcBIMQA3', 
    "RecordType" => '0126F000001hG2WQAU',
    "LastName" => "test",

);
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply chiefppk!
I made it work. Apparently one of the custom field was needed to create a Contact Object in my Organization. Though that custom field was not a required field, I'm assuming the work flow or process needed the field when Contact is newly created. It may be weird, but I somehow made it work...

Comment: Interesting.  Glad its working for you.  Good to know that even without a required field a triggered event may necessitate a field.